# java or javascript image editing library with some required functionality

Tags: java, javascript, image

I am looking for an image editing library (either Java or Javascript) that allows me to do the following--

1. Image with solid colors - can be edited, viz the color can be changed visually on screen.
2. Image with gradient colors- can be edited, ie the gradient and colors that make up the gradient can be modified visually on screen.

I would prefer something with a more permissive license like Apache License or BSD License, but if needed I can go with an open source library.

Comment: Which libraries have you considered so far? I assume a quick Google search would help.

Comment: @FelixKling- The only libraries I found through a google search had generic image processing capabilities, not the editing of gradient colors that I was looking for (eg: Pixastic).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/index.html) and see if it helps you out. You can run it as an applet and it has no license attached to it and ofcourse it is open source

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a fast and strong C/C++ Library for Image Processing and Computer Vision.

Luckely it got ported to **Java** by Samuel Audet. The wrapper is called [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/). I used it for Image Modification and Face Detection, but maybe its to cluttered for your purpose. It has a BSD License.